# include ui bootstrap in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

How do I include `ui.bootstrap`. I use `ui.bootstrap` to open the bootstrap modal(open) on `ng-click`. After that I want to send all modal data to server, for that I use `$http` in my angular controller. But it gives an error. Below is my angular js code.

```
var app = angular.module("modalFormApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller("modalAccountFormController", ['$scope', '$modal', '$log', '$http'

    function($scope, $modal, $log, $http) {

        $scope.showForm = function() {
            $scope.message = "Show Form Button Clicked";
            console.log($scope.message);

            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'modal-form.html',
                controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
                scope: $scope,
                resolve: {
                    userForm: function() {
                        return $scope.userForm;
                    }
                }
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
                $scope.selected = selectedItem;
            }, function() {
                $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });
        };
    }
]);


app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$modalInstance', userForm, function($scope, $http, $modalInstance, userForm) {

    //var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance,$http,                     userForm) {
    $scope.form = {}
    $scope.url = 'submit.php';
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        if ($scope.form.userForm.$valid) {
            $http.post($scope.url, {
                "name": $scope.name,
                "email":

                    $scope.email,
                "message": $scope.message
            }).
            success(function(data, status) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.status = status;
                $scope.data = data;
                $scope.result = data;
            })

        } else {
            console.log('userform is not in scope');
        }
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}])
```

Comment: @SatheeshSanthosh i got a below error   ..... [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module modalFormApp due to: [$injector:nomod] Module 'modalFormApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

'ui.bootstrap' has prerequisites 'ngAnimate' and 'ngTouch'. You should add them to your module

```
var app = angular.module("modalFormApp", ['ngAnimate','ngTouch','ui.bootstrap']);
```

And you should add their scripts to your view

```
script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.min.js")
script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-touch.min.js")
```